# Spark converting a Dataset to RDD

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have a Dataset[String] and need to convert to a RDD[String]. How?

Note: I've recently migrated from spark 1.6 to spark 2.0. Some of my clients were expecting RDD but now Spark gives me Dataset.

Answer (score 28):

As stated in the scala [API documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html) you can call `.rdd` on your Dataset :

```
val myRdd : RDD[String] = ds.rdd
```

Answer (score 1):

Dataset is a strong typed Dataframe, so both Dataset and Dataframe could use .rdd to convert to a RDD.